# Create sub menu outside menu-item in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, submenu

well the title says it all actually.

I want a sub-menu, to be outside the menu-item, so I can style it over the complete width of the website, also using bootstrap.

Is there a way to accomplish this?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Use this code in your current theme function.php file.

```
add_filter('wp_nav_menu_items', 'wp_sub_menu_link', 10, 2);

function wp_sub_menu_link($items, $args) {
    if ($args->theme_location == 'sub-menu') {   
            $items .= '<li class="right"><a href="/sub-page/">' . __("Sub page") . '</a></li>';
    }
    return $items;
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Hi, that does nothing unfortunately.